# Show div with javascript if form successfull

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that disappears when it gets submitted via javascript.
Now I want to have a div displayed, like a thank-you message, that displays when the form disappears instead of it. I have tried to do this but I am still learning and can't figure it out. I tried to include a "$('#thanks').show();" after the hide-command, but that didn't work. I also wonder where I would need to place the div that is initially hidden. Any help is appreciated. :)

This is my script:

```
<script>

  $(function () {
    $('#contact').on('submit', function (e) {
        var self = this; 
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'), 
            method: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                 $(self).hide(); successful 
            },
            error: function () { alert('Failed to send email'); }
        });

    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: `success: function () {
                 $(self).hide(); $("#thanks").show();
            },` should work - what happened? Errors in console?

Comment: May be you can show us a little of your html too ..

Comment: You should post your html.

Comment: The #thanks div should not be a child of #contact. If you hide the #contact the div #thanks will never be displayed

Comment: I am so sorry, I just figured it out. I had placed the thanks-div in a stupid way so it was always hidden but now it worked. I get how basic this question was, tanks for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open your console (devtools) and check if:

```
$('#thanks').show();
```

does show the div.

Also check if your #thanks element isn't inside your #contact element.
Adding

```
$('#thanks').show();
```

In the success method should just work.